# Impossible authentication situation? Hint for algorithm needed

Tags: algorithm, authentication

#### This is the situation:

Server **nor** client can be trusted (both run on users' pc's). Trusted users have a secret key on their computer, along with the client. The goal of the algorithm is to authenticate trusted users as trusted on the server without exposing the secret key to the server.

#### Technical difficulties:

The language we use (Game Maker) isn't that fast nor precise. We have an implementation of MD5 hashing ready, but me nor the team is capable of/has the time for implementing incredibly hard crypto algorithms.

Comment: How much security do you need?

Comment: I think you're looking for "zero knowledge proof"

Comment: @Skizz: Well, the data transfer doesn't have to be secure or something. All I need is that the server can authenticate trusted users without the secret key being published to anyone but trusted users. Also, if the government tries to decrypt the key with 1000 supercomputers it doesn't have to withstand the attack.

Comment: Does the server have any information about potential clients, like a key, perhaps?

Comment: @Skizz: The server can contain any public data needed - like a public key. However keep in mind that everyone can read this data.

Comment: If you don't trust the client or the server, the best you can do is obfuscation here. What's your end goal, and are you aware that no matter what you do it'll be broken by a reasonably motivated attacker?

Comment: @Nick: that depends what you mean by "trust the server". I could "not trust the server" to act in *my* best interests, but believe that it will act in its owner's best interests, in which case we need a scheme that protects trusted clients from untrusted servers, and untrusted servers from untrusted clients, but need not protect untrusted servers from themselves (which is DRM-impossible). Against eavesdropping that could be more than obfuscation (although MITM may be an intractable problem). I think the difficulty is doing it using only a hash function, and a weak-ish one at that.

Comment: Indeed, you need a zero-knowledge method, as described [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof). There is some implementation there: http://perso.crans.org/~raffo/projects.php, see at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Exactly, "protects trusted clients from untrusted servers" and "untrusted servers from untrusted clients".

Comment: @SteveJessop True. It all comes down to what your threat model is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to produce one secret per server using only MD5. I'm not sure this is correct, so don't take my word for it.

Each server has a unique ID, which can be public, and also a local secret equal to `MD5(trusted secret + unique ID)` or similar. You'll have to get the local secret onto the server by some external secure channel, but for example if it's downloaded from a single company site by HTTPS along with the server code, and if you ensure that you never send out the local secret for a given unique ID more than once, then I think that's OK.

The server can then send its ID to the client along with the server ID. A trusted client can generate `MD5(trusted secret + unique ID)` for itself, but an untrusted client can't generate it. That gives the server and the trusted client a shared secret, which can be used to authenticate using (for example) HMAC-MD5.

If a local secret leaks, then it only gives untrusted clients the ability to fool that leaky server, not other servers.

Obviously this has weaknesses - for example a MITM between a server and a trusted client can provide the correct response to any challenge the server makes, without knowing any secrets. But it doesn't expose the client's secret to the server, and it doesn't expose the server's secret to the client, so it's somewhat better than nothing.

It also has cryptographic weaknesses - MD5 is somewhat broken. If I'm a server and I can find `x` such that `MD5(x + my_id) == my_secret`, then chances are `x` is the secret key. I don't know how computationally feasible it is to find `x` given one or more local secrets: that depends on the current degree of broken-ness of MD5.

I think MITM is absolutely inevitable given your constraints, although I may be wrong. A trusted client has no way to tell one server from another, in particular whether a server is using its proper unique ID, and therefore will always give the correct responses to any challenges that a MITM passes along. However, provided that the messages include some value that the attacker cannot control, such as a server-generated nonce or the date, then simple eavesdropping doesn't lead to replay attacks. I'm not aware of a way to prevent MITM without using asymmetric encryption and a PKI, that is to say different basic crypto building blocks that you don't have the time/capacity to implement in your language.

It's possible to make the system provide for key revocation of a sort. If you set up your company authority to hand out pairs of `(random server ID, local secret)` on demand, then servers could update their local secret from time to time (and change their ID at the same time). Then you could change the trusted secret, and servers would stop authenticating clients that use the old one, and start authenticating clients that use the new one, as soon as they next get an ID. As stated that's a fairly painful handover, you'd probably want to soften it a bit if you were building in such a scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. We'll have to discuss if we're going to set up a central authority or not for giving out ID's and snapshots. If not, is there a way to do this without a central authority or is that impossible?

Comment: @nightcracker: for this scheme you certainly need to have an authority that has the secret key, and can hand out a (server ID, snapshot) pair. Furthermore, servers need a trusted means to contact that authority, since if an attacker can give a server a fake pair then of course it can pretend to be a trusted client. I can't immediately prove there isn't a cleverer scheme that doesn't need one. Of course mathematically speaking it can be done, just use asymmetric crypto, so it's an odd kind of proof, that what's required is the tools you don't have time for.

Comment: As you seem to have already realised, there's no need for "snapshotting" - your scheme is equivalent to giving untrusted clients the hash of the secret key with a nonce, allowing them to verify that others have it without knowing it themselves. I'd strongly suggest editing your question to state as much throughout, rather than appending the edit.

Comment: This reminds me of SNMP key localization e.g. http://rfc-ref.org/RFC-TEXTS/3414/kw-key_localization.html. The idea is that you use a single secret key and a variable ID of some sort to generate a localized secret key - somebody who knows the single secret can generate any localized secret, but knowing a localized secret does not tell you anything more. So you could give trusted clients the single secret and put a different localized secret on each untrusted server. Then run a protocol based on SNMPv3 to authenticate client to server.

Comment: Mention of "snapshots" removed. The uses of "snapshot" in the first two comments refer to the local secret.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on harold's comment, a zero-knowledge proof scheme appropriate for this problem is [Feige-Fiat-Shamir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feige%E2%80%93Fiat%E2%80%93Shamir_identification_scheme). Peggy proves to Victor that she knows the factorization of a large modulus without revealing it to Victor.

This scheme doesn't support revocation, which is a serious problem if you can't trust your "trusted" users not to reveal the secret.

Answer (score 0):

**You should not design your own crypto system.** Find an existing one and port it. (Even that can expose you to things like timing attacks...)

Allow me to demonstrate how easy it is to make a mistake. Here's a basic authentication scheme:

- Use RSA with public keys digitally signed by you being 'trusted'
- Server sends a random challenge to clients that have provided a signed public key
- Client responds with private-encrypted challenge
- Server verifies by decrypting to original value
- Untrusted clients can't authenticate because they have no private key for a signed public key

Seems secure, right? Nope.

- The server controls the challenge value. A malicious server can do a man-in-the-middle attack between a connecting client and another server to authenticate itself as a trusted client to the other server.
- No revocation mechanism. What if a trusted user publishes their private key?

Comment: The security doesn't have to be attack-proof. It should be fool-proof. Look, it's for a game that gives some privileges to some users, not super-secure money transfers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you dont need super secure system then server or user should "ask": `Am I trusted?` Still, some how you need to trust the user. Simple way is, when users adds the his key,  or it beaing generated, it send some signal to server that: `OK, I have validated, please remember that im trusted and here you go, the special passprase to check that: *Apple*. I should answer *Pear*.` And then when user connects to server, server ask: `Apple?`, and client answers: `Pear!`. Server authorizes client. Works both ways. Still, if you want some MUCH better solution, you will need some central server, witch will give:

- Question to server
- Answer to client
- Validates the client key